# Android ImageView resize height without loading image (like instagram, facebook)

Tags: android, imageview, height

The image I want to do is get the shape of the imageview before it comes to the screen.

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

I did it this way but the imageview does not appear because the height is wrap_content before the image is loaded. The image expands after being uploaded, but I want to get the image size without loading the image.

Comment: If you are loading images from server, ask your server to send height/width of the image. there is no other way to know size of image if you are loadind it dynamically

Comment: i think, you have to fix the min height of `ImageView` .

Comment: In which format you are getting the image from the server.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are getting the image URL / path from the server. Like, http://......

Then, you will definitely get the height and the width of the image from its path / URL by converting it into the Bitmap.

Try this:

```
try {

    URL url = new URL("http://....");// here put your string URL comes from server
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

    int width = b.getWidth(); // here is the your image width
    int height = b.getHeight(); // here is the your image height

} catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Have you got it ? @Mehmet Kurtgoz

Comment: So, for that first please explain in details what  you want to do.